# Access data in the array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

In the logs I see that the value of variable @step_attributes is:

```
@step_attributes = [#<CustomAttribute id: 7, value: "Name, Surname: ">, #<CustomAttribute id: 8, value: "Call: +555555555">]
```

I have a problem with accessing this data in order to print them. I am guessing that methods of printing of array of hashes should be working, but not for me. Can sb help me with this one?

Comment: ... What doesn't work? I don't see any hashes, rather an array of class instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are objects. You should be able to get to them with

`@step_attributes[0].value`